# Assigning NICs to a XenProject VM

Tags: networking, firewall, virtualization, assign, xen

I wish to install a VM on my Xen Project machine that will run a Zentyal Firewall. My machine has three networks cards: one integrated, and two discreet, similar cards (they have the same Realtek chip, but are from different manufacturers). For the firewall to work optimally, what I want to do is assign and dedicate the two discreet NICs to my firewall VM, and use the integrated card for Dom0 and other VMs. I have been able to do similar things with other virtualisation software in the past, but have not been able to find a way to do it with Xen Project.

[This page](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Networking) provides many useful configurations, but I don't think any of them match what I want to do. Is this at all possible, or must I give up hope of virtualising my firewall computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to solve this would be using [PCI passthrough](https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_PCI_Passthrough#Configuration_file_for_the_domU) in Xen. What this means is that you can leave 1 of your NICs attached to the dom0 (which can then be bridged to allow the other VMs to connect through the same interface - look at one of the [Xen articles on network configuration](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Network_Configuration_Examples_(Xen_4.1%2B)#Bridging) for some examples of how to set this up, it'll be the same as if you only had a single NIC) and allow the firewall VM full control over the other two NICs.

The process for this is somewhat involved and can vary by distribution so I would advise you check the first article I linked but I will describe the basic process.

Check the PCI addresses of the two network cards you want to pass through using `lspci`. The lines of output for your cards will look something like the following (although the details will be very different the structure will be the same):

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:19.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
```

Make a note of the first column (`00:19.0` and `00:19.1` in this example). Add this to the config for your firewall VM in the following format:

```
pci=['00:19.0','00:19.1']
```

On its own this will cause the VM to fail to boot as it will be unable to pass through the devices. In order for the devices to be passed through they will need to be bound to the pciback driver on dom0 with a command like:

```
xl pci-assignable-add 00:19.0
xl pci-assignable-add 00:19.1
```

This may not be possible in all situations but there are other methods if it is not. I strongly advise you to read [the article](https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_PCI_Passthrough) I mentioned before to fully understand what the best way to do this is in your case.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I was looking for - I would have accepted the answer sooner, unfortunately we gave up and went for a dedicated firewall long before this answer came in, so I did not think to check this question.